# Can Browser Helper Object be used to make an "online" ui-automation tool

Tags: c#, .net, com, bho

We are going to make a test-automation tool which resides in the browser(like an online version of Quicktest Professional). We build most of the part using html+ajax.
the problem is web application can not talk to the user's native machine's resource. Thus it is impossible to automate the user's native application. 
We come the idea of using IE extensions like Browser Helper Object but knows nothing about it.
Can anyone tell me is there restriction on Browser Helper Object accessing native windows api and COM component or is it as freely as WinForm applications?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you check out Watir:

http://watir.com/

> Watir, pronounced water, is an open-source (BSD) family of Ruby libraries for automating web browsers. It allows you to write tests that are easy to read and maintain. It is simple and flexible.

Comment: watir is only for web application automation but we also want the capability of automating windows native application.

Comment: there's another tool for UI automation in general but I can't remember the name of it. I asked my buddy who showed me it, when he gets back to me I will comment here.

Comment: http://sikuli.org/ "Sikuli is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots)." Works in Linux\Windows\OSX